# Windows batch: variable is lost after running another batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set FILENAME=testfilename
for /L %%n in (1,0,10) do (
   echo name-before: !FILENAME!
   another-batch-file
   SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
   @echo off
   echo name-after: !FILENAME!
)
@echo on
ENDLOCAL
```

When run, the following is echoed to the console:

```
name-before:testfilename
name-after:!FILENAME!
```

The variable `FILENAME` is being set to "*testfilename*", and is echoed correctly to the terminal. However, after another-batch-file completes, `FILENAME` cannot be resolved and "*FILENAME*" rather than "*testfilename*" is echoed. I have looked in the batch file which is called, but cannot see any obvious code or settings would cause this.

I wonder if there is an obvious issue.
Thanks

Comment: Check your `for /L` syntax; did you intend to write an infinite loop?

Answer (score 4):

A number of things to work on here.

1. Some general advice when debugging a batch file: Remove the `echo off` line at the top.  It's amazing what you can learn when you don't suppress your debugging information.
2. It is almost always wrong to use `setlocal` inside a loop.  Each call allocates resources for a full copy of the environment block, which you're not calling `endlocal` to deallocate.

Regarding the echoing of variables, I can't reproduce the behavior you describe.  When I run your code, I get `name-before: !FILENAME!` echoed.  This does output correctly when I use the `CALL` keyword explained below.

**I suspect the main problem is because of the way you are calling "another-batch-file" without using the CALL keyword.**  In general, you *never* want to run a batch file directly from another batch file.  The second batch completely replaces the first, and no further lines from the outer batch will run.  Effectively, it functions as an EXIT statement.

```
:: This line executes
set foo=1

:: Now run another batch file
other.cmd

:: This line never executes, because this batch was canceled when
:: the other started running
set foo=2
```

The solution is to use the `CALL` keyword to run another batch file.  Then the current one will continue executing once it's done.

```
:: Now run another batch file
CALL other.cmd

:: This line runs as normal
set foo=2
```

In your code, it's hard to tell because the loop continues until the current statement (`for /L`) has finished running, but your last `ENDLOCAL` and anything further in the file won't ever run.

Comment: `In your example, nothing is executing after the call to another-batch-file.` - then why does it print `echo name-after: !FILENAME!`?

Comment: @GSerg - Because the loop is parsed and cached in memory, and continues to run even after batch processing has terminated. But it is no longer running within the context of the batch file, and no commands after the loop will be executed.

Comment: @dbenham There were no loops in the question or the answer when I posted this.